# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large, R studio par(mfrow)

Tags: r, plot

Hi I tried to graph my histograms and it keeps giving me this message:

```
Error in plot.new : figure margins too large
```

I've tried all night googling for solutions,
even tried to make a pdf, doesn't work.

When I try to put pdf in it tells me this:

```
Error in pdf"u666.pdf", width = 27, height = 40 : 
  cannot open file 'u666.pdf'
```

I'm not sure what else I can do to graph the histograms. I've tried these lines as well but they don't give me a graph

```
graphics.off()
par("mar")
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
```

Here are the codes

```
    op <- par(mfrow=c(5,1))
    x10 <- rnorm(10, mean=PN)
    hist(x10, freq=FALSE)
    x1000 <- rnorm(1000, mean=PN)
    hist(x1000, freq=FALSE)
    x1e5 <- rnorm(1e5, mean=PN)
    hist(x1e5, freq=FALSE)
    par(op)
    dev.off()
 
    op <- par(mfrow=c(3,1))
    hist(x1e5+3, freq=FALSE,ylim=c(0,0.4))
    hist(x1e5-10, freq=FALSE,ylim=c(0,0.4))
    hist(x1e5*1.5, freq=FALSE,ylim=c(0,0.4))
    par(op)
```

Comment: The error means that the margins around each of your histograms are too large to fit all 5 on your plot. If you want to make your plots this way you can set the margins to be smaller with this code `par(mar = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))` (or some other small values) before your first `hist`

Comment: It finally worked! But it seems cut off, do I just play around with hose numbers until I am able to see it in my knitted word doc?

Comment: Yes, I think you have to play with the numbers to find a configuration that works. But I haven't used base R graphics in a while -- I usually go with ggplot. I can make an approach in a full answer.

Comment: It's Ok I got it! I put 1 instead of 0.1 and it looked better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once the error appears, making the graph window larger won't solve the problem. I made the graph window nice and large, then closed r-Studio, then re-opened r-Studio.  This worked for me.

Comment: This solution doesn't really require code and seems to be the answer, but you may perhaps have a more clear answer by providing at least some screenshots of what you mean here.